# Adafruit Feather ESP32 - GPIO power drain during deep sleep

Tags: adafruit, esp32

I have an Adafruit Feather ESP32 whose GPIOs I use to control an external device. I don't want the device to drain the power of the ESP32 sometimes, so I set the GPIOs to INPUT. When I go into deep sleep though, the GPIOs suddenly get some random voltages and start drawing power. A few GPIOs are 3.3V, others are 0.7V, and some are near 0V.

What is the correct/standard way to make the microcontroller not leak any power to that external device.
One way is obviously physically disconnecting that device, but I want an automated way. Is it solvable by software or do I need special hardware to achieve my goal?

Comment: measure the current flowing at the GPIO pins when the ESP32 is in deep sleep .... measuring the voltage tells you nothing about the current, unless you know the value of the resistance

Comment: the board has a pull-up on some pins

Comment: @jsotola Certainly I also measured the current. When I disconnect the external device, the current drops significantly.

Comment: @Jurai that is true. So I moved away from those pins. This does not entirely solve my problem though. I want the current to the external device be the same as when I disconnect the external device: 0A. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide some more information. What is the external device? How do you power this device? How is it connected? PS setting a pin to input, means it's now "floating" so it could be any voltage.

Comment: Sorry I'm not expert in the ESP32, but I know it can come out of deep sleep based on inputs from the pins. Maybe that's what's happening. The Espressif IDF at least has a way to read the reason the chip came out of deep sleep. Are you using the arduino image or micro/circuitpython?